# PL/SQL sysdate format not working?

Tags: plsql, oracle-apex, sysdate

I have a problem with sysdate formatting in PL/SQL.
I try to calculate my age, upon the day (so it should return something like 20.44).
However sysdate won't work with this format and the value v_leeftijd keeps returning -2000.91.
Obvious that isn't my age. How do I solve this?
I have the following code:

```
declare
v_vandaag date := to_date(sysdate, 'DD-MM-YYYY');
v_geboortedatum date := to_date('29-05-2014', 'DD-MM-YYYY');
v_leeftijd number(10,2);

begin

--leeftijd/dagen = leeftijd in jaren
v_leeftijd := (v_vandaag - v_geboortedatum)/365;

dbms_output.put_line(v_leeftijd);

end;
```

Comment: `[..] the value v_leeftijd keeps returning -2000.91. Obvious that isn't my age.` Congratulations, you're probably the youngest SO member ever ! How on earth you have get yourself involved with Oracle legacy technologies in such a short time ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sysdate` is already a date:

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
declare
    v_geboortedatum date := to_date('29-05-2014', 'DD-MM-YYYY');
    v_leeftijd number(10,2);
begin
    --leeftijd/dagen = leeftijd in jaren
    v_leeftijd := (sysdate - v_geboortedatum)/365;

    dbms_output.put_line(v_leeftijd);
end;
/
```

Comment: Thanks! It's working correctly now, for me. However when we run our apex-application my teammates will get a different value. Because in the Netherlands computers have a different sysdate somehow. My pc is formatted in English. How do I solve this?

Comment: Yes sysdate is the system date and is timezone dependent. You can't do anything about it, but I doubt it is an issue since all the dates you manipulate are hardcoded anyway, correct? 29-05-2014 is not necessarily the same PST or GMT. What I'm trying to say is you have to agree on a standard timezone. In the industry we usually choose UTC for storage of dates. Beware though that SYSDATE is the SYSTEM date which is different than the oracle date. It means it uses the timezone of your SERVER, not DATABASE.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! Since this is a school project, it's fine to just use the server time. But it good to remember.